# Silverstripe 4: Configuring Fluent to make Widget fields translatable

Tags: php, yaml, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I'm setting up an SS project and want to add url based locales (`/en`, `/gb`, etc) using the silverstripe-fluent addon (https://github.com/tractorcow-farm/silverstripe-fluent). I've successfully installed it and can add locales using cms but the translatable fields only work for main content. How do i make other widgets and dataobjects translatable too?

I've tried making it work for Widgets by following the github docs and doing the following listed below.

**mysite.yml**

```
Silverstripe\SiteConfig\SiteConfig:
  extensions:
    - TCM\SiteConfig\Extensions\LdaUrlExtension
    - TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentExtension
SiteTree:
  extensions:
    - TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentFilteredExtension
Widget:
  extensions:
    - TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentVersionedExtension
  translate:
    - HTMLTitle
    - HTMLContent
ContentWidget:
  extensions:
    - TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentVersionedExtension
  translate:
    - HTMLTitle
    - HTMLContent
Page:
  translate:
    - 'Heading'
    - 'Description'
---
Name: myfluentconfig
---
TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentDirectorExtension:
  disable_default_prefix: false
---
Name: fluentfieldconfig
---
TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentExtension:
  field_include:
    - Varchar(100)
    - DBHTMLText
    - HTMLTitle
    - HTMLContent
```

**PHP in widget.php or contentwidget.php**

```
private static $db = array(
        'HTMLTitle'       => 'HTMLVarchar',
        'HTMLContent'     => 'HTMLText',
        'PreviewBgImg'    => 'HTMLText',
        'TextPosition'    => 'Varchar(6)',
        'TextColour'      => 'Varchar(5)',
        'BackgroundColour' => 'Varchar(5)'
    );

private static $translate = [
        'HTMLTitle',
        'HTMLText',
        'HTMLContent'
    ];
```

I expected these to make my content widget fields also translatable but unfortunately widget content is still the same for all locales.

I've also made sure to do `dev/build?flush=all` and manually even cleared contents of `silverstripe-cache` folder.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SS4 you need the FQCN (fully qualified class name) for configuration, the class name including the full namespace. This should work in your config:

```
SilverStripe\Widgets\Model\Widget:
  extensions:
    - TractorCow\Fluent\Extension\FluentVersionedExtension
  translate:
    - HTMLTitle
    - HTMLContent
```

Similar for `ContentWidget`